# Android application uninstall batch/shell script?

Tags: android, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have developed a small application that consists of 5 different apk files. I'm developing on a lot of PCs and have a lot of developing phones. Every time I change the PC, the signature of the generated APK file is changed and I have to uninstall the applications on the phone. This is very time consuming. So is there a possibility to write a batch/file script that i can run on the PC so that the defined applications are uninstalled on the device?

I tried to do it the following way:

```
for %%f in (adb devices) do (
adb -s %%f uninstall bla.bli.blub
)
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work correctly ;)

Comment: i'm talking about the shell on the pc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally was able to get a working version of the script:

```
FOR /F "skip=1" %%P IN ('adb devices') DO (
adb -s %%P uninstall bla.blub.application1
adb -s %%P uninstall bla.blub.application2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open up a terminal
2. `cd` to the directory where you've installed the android sdk
3. `cd tools/`
4. `adb uninstall package-name`
   (where package-name is something like com.android.blah)

And of course you can put these steps in a shell script and uninstall several packages.

Comment: the problem is... i have different devices running and connected. do you know how i can go through the list of all available devices? I could hardcode them using the serial number of the device, but if this device is not connected, then there is a problem.

Comment: The you can run `adb devices` and get the device ids.

Comment: thanks. can you help me how i can store this list and then make a loop whith it?

Comment: If you know Ruby, you could write a Ruby script that runs these shell scripts. Just have the shell scripts dump their results in a file and read it in Ruby. Then you'll have a much easier time with loops, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but unfortunately i dont know Ruby :(